# SELECT query using prepared statement and setting values taken from user

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to retrieve data from database using values input by user. The values are stored in the array named uid. The code is compiling but not printing results.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Connection conn = null;

PreparedStatement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs=null;
try{
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
  String sql1="SELECT * FROM user_ratings WHERE user_id = ?";
  stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
    for (int i:uid)
  {
     stmt.clearParameters();
   stmt.setInt(1,uid[i]);

   rs=stmt.executeQuery();
  while(rs.next())
  {
     int id  = rs.getInt("user_id");
     int mid = rs.getInt("movie_id");
     int first = rs.getInt("movie_rating");
     int second = rs.getInt("acting");
     int third = rs.getInt("visuals");
     System.out.print("User ID: " +id);
     System.out.print(", Movie ID: " +mid);
     System.out.print(", First: " +first);
     System.out.println(", Second: " +second);
     System.out.println(", Third:" +third);
  }
  }
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure uid has any value? Check the length of uid.

Comment: did you debug the code? are there any query results?

Comment: uid has the following values:
uid={3,4,12,13,14,17,19,20,21,24};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement `stmt.setInt(1,uid[i]);` for sure should read `stmt.setInt(1,i);`.

You are already iterating the ?`uid` array and have each value in turn available by `i` due to using `for (int i:uid)`.

Comment: Tried it. Still didn't get any result.

Comment: Whithout an error occuring? And the debugger not revealing anything suspicious? Then I'd try unrestricted query: `SELECT * FROM user_ratings`. If this returns the table data, then try using a constant expression `SELECT * FROM user_ratings WHERE user_id=3`. If first fails then check anything related to access (USER, PASS, priviledges of USER,...). If seond check also turns out to work then check what values are used with prepared statement `setInt()` (but you should have seen this already from your debugger sessions.)

Comment: Thank You. The second check helped me find the problem. I didn't have to pass any parameters in executeQuery();